# Looking for improving the speed of a macro working with a loop and converting date to other format

Tags: excel, vba, date, for-loop, selection

My code below works but it is very slow… This code in fact consists to convert the date in column C and D of my sheet (called "Test") from format day.month.year to format day/month/year (For example please see the picture below, the lines  1-2-3-4-5 have been already converted whereas the other lines from line 1183 have not been converted yet).

I am looking for a solution  to improve the speed of this macro because if I have a lot of lines to convert in column C and D, the macro is really really slow…

If by chance someone know how to improve the speed of this macro, that would be really fantastic.

[image]

```
Sub convertdatrighteuropeanformat()
    Dim cell As Range
    Call selectallmylinesctrlshiftdown

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In Selection
        With cell
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = Format(.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        End With
    Next cell

    Selection.Replace What:="/", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub selectallmylinesctrlshiftdown()
    With Sheets("Test")
        .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure if there are calcs going on in your workbook, but you could try turning calcs to Manual and then back to Automatic at the end of the sub 
`application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: Sorry I made a confusion because I said  in my previous comment above, the macro convert all lines in column C and D from format  day.month.year to format day/month/year but in fact this is the contrary, the macro converts all lines in column C and D from format day/month/year to format day.month.year

Comment: Have you verified what your `selectallmylinesctrlshiftdown` is grabbing? If you have null data on your sheet, it could be looping through a range much larger than needed

Comment: The reason you're so slow is because you are looping and applying a number format **one cell at a time**. Also, `Selection` isn't the best of things to use. If you *manually* select something, then set that to a var as soon as the code starts - If you are using selection in your code, use vars from the start and never touch that method.

Comment: Thanks a lot ArcherBird, I wrote application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual at the beginning of my Code and I wrote at the end of my Code Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic, it is really faster now...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop, refer to the entire `Range` (previously `Selection`) at once inside the `With` block. This is combined into one sub, although there is nothing wrong with your decision to declare the range with a stand alone procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub convert()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
Dim LRow As Long, MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

LRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = ws.Range("D2:E" & LRow)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With MyRange
        .Value = Format(.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        .Replace "/", ".", xlPart, xlByRows
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Might be better to retain previous screenupdating- a macro that changes calculation settings is going to annoy many users.

Dim CalcMethod as boolean
CalcMethod=Application.Screenupdating
Do stuff
Application.Screenupdating=CalcMethod

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I've never seen anyone complain about changing calc settings when they are reverted back at end (assuming the initial setting was `Automatic`) @OwlsSleeping

Comment: I agree that if the initial setting is Automatic there are no issues. That's not guaranteed.